# setText(int resid) changing text to "false"

Tags: android

I feel like an idiot and it's probably very simple, but I can't seem to get TextView's setText(int resid) function to work.

Here's my function's code:

```
TextView t1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
TextView t2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
t1.setText(R.id.textView2);
```

I've checked that both TextViews are found by using setText with a String, but using it with an id consistently changes the value of the target TextView's text to "false".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource id in this case refers to a `String` resource id such as `R.string.your_string_name`. What you are passing right now is an integer representing a View's id. This won't work.

If you want to set the text from `t2` in `t1`, do

```
t1.setText(t2.getText());
```

Comment: Got it, I thought resid could directly point to a TextView. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Shoune You're welcome. I'm surprised that the docs don't explicitly mention that you need `R.string`s for `setText()`.